# Is there a way to get call back in linux if file/directory size increases above configured level

Tags: c++, c, linux, system-calls

am looking for some thing like this programatically in c/c++ using linux system call,

```
char * filename="/tmp/testDirectory";
fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR);

setmaxfilesize(fd,"4mb");         //<== looking for some API to do this.
registerforCallback(mycallback);  //<== looking for some API to do this 

void mycallback(void * arg)
{
 /* Delete old files inside directory to have space for new files*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not directly on the file size as I know.

Take a look at:
https://lwn.net/Articles/604686/

This will give you a good startpoint how to interact with file notifications. After a file change your handler can be notified. In the handler you can check for size and do your job.

Excerpt:
There is `dnotify` which basically works with the syscall `fcntl(fd, F_NOTIFY, mask);` 
dnotify seams to be outdated ( my linux distro has no support for dnotify anymore )

`inotify` comes with an own API. See `man inotify`.
Watching for  file change can be done with `int inotify_add_watch(int fd, const char *pathname, uint32_t mask);` where mask can be `IN_MODIFY` to see all modifications on the file. If your handler is called from here, request the file size and do your actions.

Comment: Thanks let me check whether I can achieve my requirement.

Comment: You are right! Added a little excerpt to my answer. Thanks